# Spark : Transform dataset to other dataset with optimise way

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization, apache-spark-dataset

I have a question on the Spark Operations.
I am using Spark, Scala with MySQL Database.

I am reading records from table(e.g. ABCTable) into dataset[ABCTable].
I wanted to transform dataset[ABCTable] into dataset[PQRTable] , by doing some aggregation with diff structure for dataset[ABCTable].

If I iterate **dataset[ABCTable]** I have to call **collect** method on this which impacts performance.

What are other ways to transform dataset into other struct type dataset  with an optimized way

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of the transformation you want to perform it is almost impossible to help you. In any case, Spark has support for aggregation operations, it has the most common ones built in and it also allows you implementing custom ones.

Comment: reading records from table(e.g. ABCTable). persist(...) . diff datasets with aggregation. Please, show example for detail answer. thank you.

Comment: Please provide the SQL statements involved.  And `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to store the processed records?